# Factoring $x^2 + 8x + 16 - y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

> Factor$$x^2 + 8x + 16 - y^2 .$$

First approach:
\begin{gather*}
(x^2 + 8x + 16) – y^2\\
(x + 4)^2 – y^2\\
[(x + 4) + y][(x + 4) – y]
\end{gather*}

Second approach where I mess up:
\begin{gather*}
(x^2 + 8x) + (16 - y^2)\\
x(x + 8) + (4 + y)(4 - y)\\
x + 1(x + 8)(4 + y)(4 - y)
\end{gather*}

I think I am breaking one of algebra's golden rules, but I cannot find it.

Comment: You have not told us what the problem is.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prove?

Comment: Math renders nicer if you include it between `$..$`. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: As far as I can tell, he is trying to factor $x^{2} + 8x + 16 - y^{2}$ two ways, but I'm rather baffled by the last step of the second "proof".

Comment: Yeah, sorry guys. I didn't mean to be so vague. Like @AWertheim says, I'm trying to factor the original problem 2 ways. Sorry this is my very first post here and I'm not very math literate as you all can probably tell.

Comment: @JohnBowlinger The last step in the second proof is wrong. I still cannot make out how you have arrived at the result. However the first proof is absolutely correct !

Comment: Thank you @lsp. I thought since x(x + 8) is being added to (4 + y)(4 - y) rather then multiplied, there would be a 1 there. Obviously it's wrong, but I don't know how?

Answer (score 1):

Let us fix your second approach. 
$$
\begin{align}
&x^2+8x+16-y^2\\
=&x^2+8x+(4-y)(4+y)\\
=&x^2+x\big[(4-y)+(4+y)\big]+(4-y)(4+y)\\
=&(x+4-y)(x+4+y).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Staring at this problem. Walk me through how x^2 + 8x + (4 -y)(4 + y) == x^2 + x[(4-y) + (4 + y)] + (4 - y)(4 + y). What happened to the 8x and why [(4 - y) + (4 + y)]?

Comment: @JohnBowlinger $8x=x[(4-y) +(4+y)]$

Comment: Where are the y's coming from?